# How to extract all rows from a large postgres table using python efficiently?

Tags: python, postgresql, fetch, psycopg2, data-extraction

I have been able to extract close to 3.5 mil rows from a postgres table using python and write to a file. However the process is extremely slow and I'm sure not the most efficient.
Following is my code:

```
import psycopg2, time,csv
conn_string = "host='compute-1.amazonaws.com' dbname='re' user='data' password='reck' port=5433"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
quert = '''select data from table;'''
cursor.execute(quert)

def get_data():
    while True:
        recs = cursor.fetchmany(10000)

        if not recs:
            break

        for columns in recs:
            # do transformation of data here
            yield(columns) 

solr_input=get_data()

with open('prc_ind.csv','a') as fh:
    for i in solr_input:
        count += 1

        if count % 1000 == 0:
             print(count)

         a,b,c,d = i['Skills'],i['Id'],i['History'],i['Industry']
         fh.write("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}\n".format(a,b,c,d))
```

The table has about 8 mil rows. I want to ask is there is a better, faster and less memory intensive way to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you profiled it? Where is the bottleneck, and what are the constraints on time/memory/cpu/disk?

Comment: Probably, just make a dump via Postgres for this task

Comment: if these are your real db credentials I suggest you delete this question, change your credentials on the server (and anywhere in your code), and paste your question again (without the db credentials).

Comment: @Loïc no these are made up credentials

Comment: @ChadS. I haven't profiled yet but I'll do it. All I wanted to know was whether my method has glaring programming flaw in it or not

Comment: Curious -why do you want to output that volume of data into a flat file format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see four fields, so I'll assume you are selecting only these.

But even then, you are still loading 8 mil x 4 x n Bytes of data from what seems to be another server. So yes it'll take some time.

Though you are trying to rebuild the wheel, why not use the PostgreSQL client?

```
psql -d dbname -t -A -F"," -c "select * from users" > output.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Psycopg2's copy_to command does the exact same thing as a psql dump, as Loïc suggested, except it's in the python side of things. I've found this to be the fastest way to get a table dump.

The formatting for certain data types (such as hstore/json and composite types) is a bit funky, but the command is very simple.

```
f = open('foobar.dat', 'wb')
cursor.copy_to(f, 'table', sep='|', columns=['skills', 'id', 'history', 'industry'])
```

Docs here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to